# WiX: How to get if this is "Installed" state in c# custom action function?

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have a custom action c# function which need to know inside what is the state "Installed" or "NOT Installed". 
How to get this state?

I.e. I need to know this state (Installed OR NOT Installed) in c# custom action

```
<Custom Action="CA_myfun" After="PublishProduct">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the custom action is scheduled for immediate execution:

```
bool installed = session.EvalulateCondition("Installed");
```

Comment: BTW, it's usually suboptimal to use Not Installed, Installed and REMOVE="ALL" for your custom action conditions.  This doesn't scale to situations where an installer has more then one feature , the user is doing maintenance operations, repairs, patches, upgrades and so on.  Usually you want to use feature or component installation and action states to drive it.  Once you get to the point of reusable data driven custom actions you typically create custom tables with a Component_ column (foreign key to Component table ) and use that to describe when something happens.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to use one custom c# function which will do changes in IIS when product is installing and will remove these changes on uninstalling. I'd like to use one function call and inside it to check what to do. it seems I need to check "Not installed" and "REMOVE=\"ALL\"" as a parameters in EvaluateCondition?

Comment: Let me try again. Imagine this scenario: You install like you propose, something breaks your IIS changes and you do a repair.  Your custom action won't run so you have to uninstall / reinstall to get it to work.